# How to add a newly created column into the existing table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a column `MONTH_APPLICATION` based on the column `DATE_APPLICATION`. I could extract the month already but I'm having trouble putting it into the table. Can anyone show me the correct way to insert the month column I've just created to the table without showing NULL values?

Month column extracted

[image: 1]

New month column in the table showing NULL values

[image: 2]

Comment: Please post table DDL and SQL in text, not pictures.

Comment: Please, paste your code and sample data in text format

Comment: 1) You should not use a `varchar` datatype to store a number, use a numeric datatype. 2) Don't store the same information twice, there is no point. Just query it when you need it, or add a computed column if required. Trying to keep a column which depends on another column up-to-date is complicated and unncessary.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend adding the column as a computed column.  If you want the month number:

```
alter table application add month_application as (month(date_application));
```

A computed column is calculated when it is referenced.  Hence, there is no need for an `update` and the value is always up-to-date.

Note:  There is little need for an additional column in this case, because it is so easy to calculate.  Also, the month without the year is often not so useful.  If you want a date which is the first day of the month, then you can use:

```
datefromparts(year(date_application), month(date_application) 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want one `ALTER TABLE` statement to add the column and then an `UPDATE` statement to populate it. (I'm not sure if you're expecting the `ALTER TABLE` line in your screenshot to know about your previous `SELECT`, but it won't. There's no connection between them, so the month_application column is created empty.)

So

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.application ADD month_application nvarchar;
UPDATE dbo.application SET month_application = MONTH(date_application);
SELECT * FROM dbo.application;
```

As pointed out in the comments, this populates the column once. If you add or change rows in the future, month_application will not automatically match date_application. Any application/person inserting or updating rows would need to be aware of that and take appropriate action (this might not be a big deal if the table rarely changes or is only changed by a single application). But since it appears these columns should always be correlated, you should look into using a view, calculated column, or trigger.

Comment: It will also require to put the month value into every `insert` statement. To make column computable it can be added as calculated column or as calculated column in view on top of the table.

Comment: OP may also want to change it to not-nullable after the update.